# How to remove error messages

Tags: php

If I'm trying to execute the code below.
I get errors when the user isn't online on TS.

but I want it to return `false` is this possible somehow?

code:

```
$client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByName($input);

    if ($client == true) {

        $TSonline = "true";
    }
    else {
        $TSonline = "false";
    }
}
echo $TSonline;
```

Comment: I think this may be what you are looking for?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Like `return $client`?

Comment: Depends. What is `ts3_VirtualServer`?

Comment: As per the accepted answer, this question seems to omit all relevant information, thus won't be useful for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
try {

    $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByName($input);
    if ($client){
        $tsOnline = true;
    } else {
        $tsOnline = false;
    }

} catch (Exception $e) { // or whatever exception is available... 

    $tsOnline = false;

}
if ($tsOnline){
    /* do your stuff */
}
```